# Proof of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Say A $\in M^{nxn}(F)$. Prove that the following propositions are equivalent:
>
> i) $\lambda \in F$ is an eigenvalue of A
>
> ii) The system $(A-\lambda I_n)X=0$ has nontrivial solutions
>
> iii) $\exists v \in F^n $- {$0$} such that $Av=\lambda v$
>
> iv)$\lambda \in F$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial $p_A(\lambda) =det(\lambda I_n -A) $

Let's prove first i $\leftrightarrow$ iii

If $\lambda \in F$ is an eigenvalue of A $\leftrightarrow \exists v \in F^n - ${$0$} such that $Av = \lambda v$ for the definition of an eigenvalue

Then: ii $\leftrightarrow$ iii

If the system $(A-\lambda I_n)X=0$ has nontrivial solutions
$\rightarrow$ $\exists v \in F^n $- {$0$} such that $(A-\lambda I_n)v =0 $ i.e $Av=\lambda v$

And at last iv $\leftrightarrow$ iii

iv) If $\lambda \in F$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial $p_A(\lambda)=det(\lambda I_n -A) \leftrightarrow det(\lambda I_n -A) =0 \leftrightarrow A-\lambda I_n  $ is non-singular $\leftrightarrow \exists v \in F^n - {$0$}$ such that $ Av = \lambda v$

Can I get feedback if this proof is complete?

Comment: Your proof looks OK to me!

Comment: Whag is thf precise definition of eigenvalue in your lecture? The i<->iii equivalence is a bit unusual if it is just the definition